# Set font attribute for UILabel UITextField in Xcode 6 GM Interface Builder

Tags: ios, macos, interface-builder, xcode6

I trying to change font of UILabel

[image: screenshot]

What is that? Is this a local Xcode bug on my Mac or global?
Or am I doing something wrong?

Anybody has this trouble?

Thaks a lot!

P.s iOS and OS X projects

Answer (score 0):

You should upgrade your XCode 5 to XCode 6 now. I had the same issue with Xcode GM and now that I have upgraded it is fixed.